# Setting up Xubuntu alongside 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, xubuntu

I have the Xubuntu downloaded. xubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-i386.iso ,,,,I am now running on Ubuntu 14.04, side by side WIN 7. I downloaded Xubuntu iso as per suggestion, to overcome slow running of 14,04

The Question is: How do I Set up Xubuntu, side by side 14.04? Can I do that without CD? Please Help

Answer (score 1):

Xubuntu is Ubuntu, but with an alternate desktop environment. Just run `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` in a terminal. Then log out and click the gear icon that appears next to your name in the password box. Select `Xubuntu Desktop` (it might be `XFCE`) from the menu and log back in. You'll now be in Xubuntu. If you want to switch back, just select `Ubuntu Desktop` in that same menu.

Comment: Thanks for the help... since the I did try and succeed in setting up Xubuntu, side by side... Best wishes

Answer (score 0):

**PART ONE**:

Before you begin, you will need to allocate free space to create a partition to install xubuntu on.

Otherwise, if you plan to shrink the windows partition instead, proceed.

It is possible to use `unetbootin` to install without a CD. First, install `unetbootin`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

Then, start `unetbootin`:

```
sudo -i unetbootin
```

Down on the lower left, put a dot by clicking the option for **disk image**. Make sure **ISO** is selected and all the way to the right, click on  <kbd>. . .</kbd>  and navigate to the xubuntu iso image you downloaded earlier.

Next, for **Space used to preserve files across reboots**, select **0**(zero).

Click on the drop-down menu for **Type:** and select **Hard Disk**.

Leave the **Drive:** set to **/** and then click  <kbd>OK</kbd> .

---

**PART TWO**:

Now, when you reboot, you should have a couple of extra options on your grub menu. Choose either **unetbootin** or **install xubuntu** or something similar.

Sometimes, one of these may not work and you may have to choose the other if one of these options does not successfully boot.

Next, when you get to the part of the installation where it asks if you would like to install xubuntu **alongside windows** or **alongside your existing operating system** . . . **choose the option "something else"**.

From here you will be able to right click on the **unallocated space** or the partition you wish to resize.

As discussed earlier, you will not be able to resize your existing Ubuntu partition through this option because Unetbootin is installed on that partition and you cannot edit a partition while it is mounted. If you like, you can resize (shrink) your existing windows partition from this menu.

Anyhow, right click on the **unallocated space** you wish to use for Xubuntu, select **create new** partition, select **ext4** as the** type** and set the mountpoint to **/**.

If a swap partition does not exist, you will want to create one now, however, don't worry about creating a *new* swap partition as you can share the *existing* swap partition.

When you have finished partitioning, proceed with the installation as normal.

Comment: Thank you.. since then I did set up side by side the original Ubuntu. and am running both Ubuntu 14.04 and Xubuntu.. thanks a lot best eishes - hariharan